# PHP/JSON Array - From iTunes

Tags: php, json

I've just started out learning PHP/JSON and I've kind of worked out how to output an array from an json file. My aim is to output all the album titles in `<li>'`s (in this case they are called **collectionName** in the json file). I think I maybe going about it the wrong way though.

```
$artistId = '644708';    
$otherAlbumsURL = 'http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='. $artistId .'&entity=album';
$a = (array)json_decode(file_get_contents($otherAlbumsURL));
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: if you want json_decode return an array, passe the second parameter true.

http://br.php.net/json-decode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an array, just use:

```
$a = json_decode(file_get_contents($otherAlbumsURL), true);
var_dump($a);
```

Setting the second parameter in [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to TRUE will give you an associative array instead of an object.

Judging from the response of the URL, you'll need to loop through the result like this in order to get any available collection names (the first array element doesn't contain a collection name because it is information about the artist. i.e. it isn't an album):

```
$artistInfo = $a['results'][0]; //Assign artist info to its own variable.
unset($a['results'][0]); //Delete artist info from the array.

//Loop through the results
foreach($a['results'] as $result){
    //$result['collectionName'] has the collection name.
    echo $result['collectionName'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't focus on a certain object (is that what they are called?) - for example collectionName?

Comment: This is spot on, I don't think I would of got that on my own - even after reading php.net. Anyhow, I can now see how this works and can put it into practise. Thanks!